# Python - scrabble word count

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I need to write a short program for scrabble where given a word it can calculate the score.

I am new to python and still figuring out how to combine lists.
Any help or an explanation to the solution would be much appreciated.

I think i have to state that each list is equal to a number and then using that work out how to look at a word and calculate that score.

Would anyone be able to give me a solution and talk me through the various points?

```
one_letter_point = ['e', 'a', 'o', 't', 'i', 'n', 'r', 's', 'l', 'u'] 
two_letter_point = ['d', 'g']
three_letter_point = ['c', 'm', 'b', 'p']
four_letter_point = ['h', 'f', 'w', 'y', 'v']
five_letter_point = ['k']
eight_letter_point = ['j', 'x']
ten_letter_point = ['q', 'z']

def scrabble_word_count(word):

    one_letter_word = 1 #do the same for the rest and then not sure what to do

    return scrabble_word_count(word) # not sure if this is supposed to be done 

print answer_word('zoo')
```

I have this alternate method, but it only looks at the first letter and gives me the point for that. e.g. points for apple = 1. as it only looks at the a.

```
def scrabble_word_count(word):
   score = 0
   for letter in word:
    if letter in one_letter_point:
        score += 1
    elif letter in two_letter_point:
        score += 2
    elif letter in three_letter_point:
         score += 3
    elif letter in four_letter_point:
         score += 4
    elif letter in five_letter_point:
          score += 5
    elif letter in eight_letter_point:
          score += 8
    elif letter in ten_letter_point:
          score += 10
    return score

    print(scrabble_word_count('apple'))
```

Comment: Your code has indentation error

Comment: A better way is with a dictionary that maps letters to scores. `{"a": 1, "b": 3, ...}`

Comment: @Barmar I can do that way, its much simpler  but I've been told I have to do it this way.

Comment: The answer's here are correct in that you should make a mapping from letters to scores. If you want to expand this to doing more complex things (like taking into account multipliers), then have a look at the scrabble project I did in college: https://github.com/FermenFlo/Scrabble-Solver/blob/master/src/Scrabble.py#L229. You can see we have a `score_map` attribute as well. feel free to poke around.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correspondance between letters and value, the better to get quick access is to have a simple correspondance for each letter.

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
         "x": 8, "z": 10}
```

Then for each letter of the word, find it in the `score dict` and sum all

```
# simple for loop style
def scrabble_word_count(word):
    res = 0
    for letter in word:
        res += score[letter]
    return res

# functionnal style
def scrabble_word_count(word):
    return sum(map(score.get, word))
```

---

Using separate lists :

```
one_letter_point = ['e', 'a', 'o', 't', 'i', 'n', 'r', 's', 'l', 'u']
two_letter_point = ['d', 'g']
three_letter_point = ['c', 'm', 'b', 'p']
four_letter_point = ['h', 'f', 'w', 'y', 'p']
five_letter_point = ['k']
eight_letter_point = ['j']
ten_letter_point = ['q', 'z']

def scrabble_word_count(word):
    res = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in one_letter_point:
            res += 1
        elif letter in two_letter_point:
            res += 2
        elif letter in three_letter_point:
            res += 3
        elif letter in four_letter_point:
            res += 4
        elif letter in five_letter_point:
            res += 5
        elif letter in eight_letter_point:
            res += 8
        elif letter in ten_letter_point:
            res += 10
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been tasked on showing this both ways. 
one with the mapping and one as above. I understand the mapping method, as it is much simpler to use. However, when doing it the way Ive been told to do I do not understand what to do with the individual lists.

Comment: That's not a bad assignment, because it means you need to learn how to think up multiple ways to solve some problem. @ps

Comment: @ps start with this: suppose that there are only two kinds of letters: those worth one point, and those worth zero. How could you check to see if a letter is in that list of one-letter points? (If you don't know, you can just google "how check list membership python). Then once you have that written and working, add a second list to the equation...

Comment: @BenQuigley 
would it be something like
x, z in eight_letter_point and ten_letter_point

Comment: @ps i've had the version with lists, something else ?

Comment: @ps No, because Python evaluates that snippet this way: `(tuple(x, z) in eight_letter_point) and (ten_letter_point)`. This will evaluate in a way that you don't want. Instead, you would write `if x in eight_letter_point and z in ten_letter_point`... But why do you have two variables now? Try writing your logic out in pseudocode / English in code comments before you actually start writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Good start, but your data structure creates a problem. Okay, so with `five_letter_point = ['k']`, we know that a 'k' is worth five points. How can we extract that data from the fact that it's stored under a variable name containing the word "five"? We really can't.

Let's use a `dict` instead, which is also known outside the context of Python as a hashmap. For example with `secret_identities = {"Batman": "Bruce Wayne", "Kal-El": "Superman"}` you can look up `secret_identities['Batman']` and learn that Batman is Bruce Wayne. Or in your case:

```
letter_scores = {
    'e': 1,
    'a': 1,
    ...
    'd': 2,
    ...
}
```

Now the scores are stored as a dict, which maps each letter to the number of points that it gets. For instance, you can look the score for `'e'` up with `letter_scores['e']`, which should return the number `1`.

Comment: Thank you, I have been asked to do it this way, I have done a version using mapping already

Comment: Sorry @IzaakvanDongen!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `if` statements to add to the appropriate value to the score depending on which list the letter is in.

```
def scabble_word_count(word):
    score = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in one_letter_point:
            score += 1
        elif letter in two_letter_point:
            score += 2
        elif letter in three_letter_point:
            score += 3
        ...
    return score
```

You can avoid all the repeated code by putting all the letter lists into another list. Use empty lists for the points that don't have any letters.

```
all_letters = [
    one_letter_point, two_letter_point, three_letter_point, four_letter_point, five_letter_point, 
    [], [], [], eight_letter_point, [], ten_letter_point
]
def scrabble_word_count(word):
    score = 0
    for letter in word:
        for index, letters in enumerate(all_letters):
            if letter in letters:
                score += index + 1 # indexes start at 0, points start at 1
                break
    return score
```

Comment: Thank you, 
for the first one, how do i get it to look at the rest of the word as well. When i try it, it only looks at the first letter and gives me the points for that one. 
and for the second method, it gives an error of too much to 'unpack'

Comment: `for letter in word` should make it look at all the letters. Make sure the `return score` statement is not in the loop.

Comment: In the second one I forgot to call `enumerate()` to get the indexes.

Comment: You could put empty lists there.